# When I move content, incremental publishing is not removing the content from the web server?

Tags: content-management-system

We have a patched 6.7 Percussion Rhythmyx CMS server and are experiencing a problem where when we move items, the incremental is not removing the item from the old location when the editions runs.  The content lists are set to unpublish/publish.

This is a problem because Google holds a link to the item at the old location so is pointing at old content in Search Results.

Is there something else that we need to set (other than the unpublish flag) to get the edition to remove the content?  All of our editions have unpublish set except Publish Now.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this can be controlled by a setting in the rxconfig server.properties file that is off by default.

```
###############################################################################
# Set this property here is the same as set the same parameter for all
# content lists, which indicates to un-publish an item from its previous
# published location if the published location has been changed.
# The server property, sys_unpublishChangedLocation=true, overwrites the same
# parameter specified in the content list; otherwise the parameter specified
# in the content list will be considered.
sys_unpublishChangedLocation=true
```

Setting this to true will cause the item to be unpublished on a move.

Without this setting, un-publish will only look at the state of the items, not the location.